# Desktop Application Crawler

Tags: c#, user-interface, web-crawler

Good Morning,

I am looking at the feasibility of generating a Desktop Application Crawler. This application crawler would work in a similar way to a web crawler - it would interrogate the application to obtain a UI structure. To fit with other ongoing projects this would be coded in C#.

The program would be able to get Window and Control properties and generate a list of which controls are present on which Windows.

Is such a thing possible? - I assume it is as projects like Microsoft's UI Spy do a similar job. The output would be a simple XML format.

Thanks in Advance, 
JH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also it not very clear what you *exactly* mean, but for investigating the content of specified WinsowsApp written in `.NET` you can use [ManagedSpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx).

Is you want ot have some *mertics* information delivered to you in  a way of service you can relay one [Desk Metrics](http://deskmetrics.com/) (they have a free of charge plan too)

If it's not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: Tigran - Manage Spy is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the assistance!